# Not able to direct upload to different region

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I am trying to change the AWS S3 bucket used by active_storage. My original entry was as follows

```
# config/storage.yml
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
  region: 'us-east-1'
  bucket: 'us-bucket-name'
```

This works fine. But I want to change it to a new bucket, called `aus-bucket-name` that is in the Sydney region, with region code `ap-southeast-2`. So I am using

```
# config/storage.yml
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
  region: 'ap-southeast-2'
  bucket: 'aus-bucket-name'
```

When I try to upload to the bucket, in the heroku server logs I see

```
 S3 Storage (1.9ms) Generated URL for file at key: xyz (https://aus-bucket-name.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/...
```

but nothing happens, the uploading page just waits, but nothing is uploaded. I am using the `direct_upload.js` progress indicator, but the file-name box does not show any activity.

If I go back to the 'us-east-1' region, then the file upload works fine, but I have a couple of extra file upload boxes when the file is loading from us-east region

[image]

so it looks like the uploads from the sydney region are still pending. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the `aus-bucket-name` did not have the correct CORS permissions, i.e it was different from the `us-bucket-name`.  When I set the CORS permissions properly, it worked fine. See this [post](https://keithpblog.org/post/active-storage-on-amazon-s3/) for a description on how to set the CORS permissions for Amazon.